# Transparent background of QLabel

Tags: android, c++, qt, transparency, qtstylesheets

I have an application on Qt with many labels. The background of each should be transparent, and on PC it is (don't mind the font size):

[image: Screenshot of th application on Ubuntu]

But when I compile my app for android and run it I get this:

[image: Screenshot of th application on Android]

Here is how I set the transparency now:
`label.setStyleSheet("background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);");`

I have also tried:
`label.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;");`
`label.setStyleSheet("background-color: none;");`

Every method works on PC and doesn't works on android. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in Qt that was reported in January.

You can track [the bug report here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43635).

It's marked as priority P2, so it's not guaranteed that it'll be fixed in the next version, but there's a chance.

Comment: So there are no way to do them transparent?

Comment: @Efog not that I know of, I'm afraid you'll have to find some sort of workaround in the meantime.